# Как одним запросом перезаписать документы в MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Есть `n` документов в коллекции в базе, есть `m` документов для записи в коллекцию, каждый документ имеет уникальный идентификатор `"user"`, общий вид `{"user": "22", "info": {...}}`.

**Суть вопроса:** Как мне одним присестом `m` документов запихнуть в коллекцию, причем так, чтоб если `user` совпал, он перезаписывал этот документ, а если нет - добавлял его в коллекцию?
Ползал по документации, не нашел.

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно [использовать](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) атрибут upsert=true

```
db.collection.update(query, update, {upsert: true})
```